# A question about pullbacks of $C^\infty_M$-modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, modules

First, let me state a definition: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and suppose $\mathcal{E}$ is a sheaf of $C^\infty_M$-modules. Given a point $x \in M$ let $I_x$ denote the vanishing ideal at $x$. We define the **fiber** of $\mathcal{E}$ at $x$ to be as follows:
$$Fib(\mathcal{E})_x := \mathcal{E}/I_x \mathcal{E} $$
At each point in $x \in M$ there is a natural evaluation map $ev_x \colon \mathcal{E} \to Fib(\mathcal{E})_x$ obtained by passing to the quotient. We say that $\mathcal{E}$ is **fiber determined** if it has the following property: For all $\sigma \in \mathcal{E}(U)$, $\sigma = 0$ if and only if for all $x \in U$ we have that $ev_x(\sigma) = 0$.

Now suppose $\pi \colon E \to N$ is a vector bundle over $N$ and denote the sheaf of sections of $E$ by $\Gamma(E)$. Let us choose an arbitrary submodule $\mathcal{W} \subset \Gamma(E)$.

It is not difficult to show that both $\Gamma(E)$ and $\mathcal{W}$ are fiber determined. My aim is to see if this property is preserved under pullbacks.

Suppose $f \colon M \to N$ is smooth. Consider the algebraic base change of $\mathcal{W}$ along $f$ to get the pullback sheaf of modules:
$$f^* \mathcal{W} = C^\infty_M \otimes_{f^{-1}C^\infty_N} f^{-1}\mathcal{W}$$

The sections of this sheaf can locally be represented by expressions of the form:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n u^i \otimes e_i  \qquad \{ u^i \}_{i=1}^n \subset C^\infty_M, \quad  \{ e_i \}_{i=1}^n \subset f^{-1}\mathcal{W}$$

My question: "Is $f^* \mathcal{W}$ fiber determined?"

Some remarks:

- If $\mathcal{W}$ is the sections of a subbundle of $E$ then this result is true. One can use local triviality to compute $f^*\mathcal{W}$ explicitly.
- One can use local normal forms for submersions to show that the claim holds for submersions.
- One can show that there is a canonical isomorphism $Fib(f^*\mathcal{W})_x \to Fib(\mathcal{W})_{f(x)}$.
- Although my main interest is in the setting of smooth manifolds. I would be curious to know if the answer differs for analytic/holomorphic manifolds.

Edits: I have tried to modify the question so that it is more clear.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829878/non-zero-sections-of-sheaves-which-vanish-on-all-fibers for an example of a non fiber determined module.